# UITapGestureRecognizer ignored after animation

Tags: animation, gesture

I've attached a tap gesture to a view, at first it seemed to work, but after animation the view the gesture is complete ignored until the view is back at it's original position.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tap:)];
[self.cellView addGestureRecognizer:tap];
[tap release];
```

In here I animate the view to the right

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 
                      delay:0.0 
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction 
                 animations:^
 {
     [cellView setFrame:CGRectMake(cellViewX, cellView.frame.origin.y, cellView.frame.size.width, cellView.frame.size.height)];
     [editView setFrame:CGRectMake(editViewX, editView.frame.origin.y, cellView.frame.size.width, cellView.frame.size.height)];
 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished)
{
    NSLog(@"Animation complete");
}];
```

The completion handler is triggered, but now the tap gesture is completely being ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, turns out I just made a stupid copy/paste error, I accidentally used the wrong values when setting the frame for the animations

```
[cellView setFrame:CGRectMake(cellViewX, cellView.frame.origin.y, cellView.frame.size.width, cellView.frame.size.height)];
[editView setFrame:CGRectMake(editViewX, cellView.frame.origin.y, cellView.frame.size.width, cellView.frame.size.height)];
```

Had to be

```
[cellView setFrame:CGRectMake(cellViewX, cellView.frame.origin.y, cellView.frame.size.width, cellView.frame.size.height)];
[editView setFrame:CGRectMake(editViewX, editView.frame.origin.y, editView.frame.size.width, editView.frame.size.height)];
```

So yes, when you copy/past code around midnight, make sure to double check it in the morning! :)